# Conversion array with float values in the array with the values of str

Tags: python, numpy

There is an array with the values of `float` which was prepared as follows:

```
import numpy as np
result256 = np.linspace(0, 2, 20)
```

It is necessary to get an array of `result 256` with values `str`.

Comment: Give us a sample case?

Comment: @Divakar I put a simple example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
result256str = []
for num in result256: result256str.append(str(num))
```